# Clean way to insert the byte representation of an IEEE float into a Python ctypes uint32 field?

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm working with an externally-provided ctypes struct that has some fields defined as general purpose catch-all fields. The *type* of the `data` field is based on the *value* of the `mode` field, as seen in this example:

```
CONTAINS_ONE_FLOAT = 1

class TestStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    pass

TestStruct._fields_ = [
    ('mode', ctypes.c_uint32),
    ('data', ctypes.c_uint32 * 2)
]
```

I need to store a single-precision (32-bit) floating point value in `data` whenever `mode` is set to `CONTAINS_ONE_FLOAT`. The second word of `data` is not used in this mode.

I have thus far only been able to figure out this approach using ctypes casting. It seems WAY too verbose, but it works.

```
float_value = 42.42
float_value_c = ctypes.c_float(float_value)
float_value_cp = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)(float_value_c)
int_val_p = ctypes.cast(float_value_cp, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint32))
int_val = int_val_p.contents

x = TestStruct()
x.mode = CONTAINS_ONE_FLOAT
x.data[0] = int_val

print("Should be 1110027796: " + str(x.data[0]))
```

Is there a better way to do this that doesn't require 5 steps?

Comment: In one line you could use  `ctypes.c_float.from_buffer(x.data).value = 42.42`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html):

```
float_bytes = struct.pack('=f', float_value)
x.data[0] = struct.unpack('=I', float_bytes)[0]
```

Comment: I had to add `[0]` to the end of the second statement since `unpack()` returns a tuple. Otherwise this works and doesn't require me to modify the underlying structure, which is provided to me and isn't easily edited.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you describe is normally implemented in C with a `union`; you can do the same with ctypes:

```
CONTAINS_ONE_FLOAT = 1

class TestStructData(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [
        ('one_float', ctypes.c_float), 
        ('two_dword', ctypes.c_uint32 * 2)
    ] 

class TestStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('mode', ctypes.c_uint32),
        ('data', TestStructData)
    ]
```

To read/write your float (or whatever other type there is), read/write in the appropriate field of `TestStructData`.

Comment: This is the best answer w.r.t. the original design of the structs, but unfortunately mine are externally provided and I can't change them to include the union. I did a timing experiment and this was about twice as fast as the struct pack/unpack solution. I also tried using a separate union just for the conversion, but it was about as fast as struct pack/unpack.